# CSS/Javascript element vertically fixed between 2 coordinates

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, coordinates, fixed

I would like to make a div that is fixed vertically but after a point (a coordinate for instance) he stops following and stays where he is. 
thanks for answers!!

Comment: Where is your attempt at it?

Comment: I believe you should do some research may be this website could help: http://www.flipkart.com/ (I am not advertising ;))

Comment: i'm looking for it since hours

Comment: This div stops following what?

Comment: it stops after at an absolute predefined coordinate

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edited question and question tags, I assume you want to make a fixed position div to stay at a particular position even when you are scrolling.

(And maybe you have done it already but it does not work, if that's the case please provide some related code)

This can be done by setting the div's position and the top/right/bottom/left in css.

```
#my_div{
position: fixed;
top: 0px; 
left: 0px;
}
```

This will set your div fixed on the window's top-left corner no matter what.

Here's a short but clear tutorial on css positioning, have a look if you have some time :)

[Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)